# automaticly serialize object via web service

Tags: object, service, web

I have my webservice method which sends an object as a result, for example:

```
public Dog GetDog();
```

where dog looks like this:

```
  public class Dog{
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public int Age{ get; set;}
}
```

Is there any way how to set the default serialization method without having to change the method to:

```
   public string GetDog(){
return dog.toString();
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about .net web services. Here is the trick.

```
[WebMethod]
public Dog GetDog()
{
  //method code
} 

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public class Dog{
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public int Age{ get; set;}
}
```

You can read this article for further understanding.
http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/26/737.aspx

Comment: thanks, thats exactly want I needed!:) any idea how to send objects to web service as well, to insert it as parameter to web service method?

Comment: also could it be serialized by JSON instead of XML? and coudl the message be encrypted?

Comment: Kindly give rating to answer if it is helpful for you. I will answer your further question later.

Comment: by clicking the check sign next to the question?

Comment: Read this article, i hope it resolves all your concerns. http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494. Also, can you please upvote my answer by pressing the up arrow button.